# I am getting OleDb Exception (Cannot update. Database or object is read-only). Im trying to insert csv file to my mysql database using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, csv

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            string path = textBox2.Text;
            string StudentNumber = "";
            string FirstName = "";
            string LastName = "";
            string Grade = "";

            string Section = "";
            string Letter = "";

            OleDbConnection my_con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=@" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
            my_con.Open();

            OleDbCommand icmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [dataGridView1_Data$]", my_con);

            OleDbDataReader dr = icmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                StudentNumber = dr[0].ToString();
                FirstName = dr[1].ToString();
                LastName = dr[2].ToString();
                Grade = dr[3].ToString();
                Section = dr[4].ToString();
                Letter = dr[5].ToString();

                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog='studentinfo';username=root;password=");
                connection.Open();

                MySqlCommand icmmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO studenttable(StudentNumber, FirstName, LastName, Grade, Section, Letter)VALUES(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f)", connection);
                icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", StudentNumber);
                icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", FirstName);
                icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("c", LastName);
                icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d", Grade);
                icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("e", Section);
                icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f", Letter);
                icmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("data Imported");
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
        else if (textBox2.Text == "")
        {

        }
```

I am getting a OleDb exception 
(Cannot update. Database or object is read-only).
I am trying to insert the csv to my mysql table.
Tried this fromcode here[[To insert csv file into mysql database table using c# windows form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825638/to-insert-csv-file-into-mysql-database-table-using-c-sharp-windows-form][1]). I still new to c# and mysql.

Comment: Did you check if your Excel file has the ReadOnly flag set?

Comment: My excel csv file is already disabled read-only. I also try it enabled read-only but still nothing works.

Comment: I also did try import my csv file through phpmyadmin and it works fine.

Comment: The error happens on the _my_con.Open();_ line?

Comment: Try changing the final part of Excel's connectionstring to _...Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1'");_

Comment: Another error occured(External table is not in the expected format). Im searching on this problem . ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1'");

Comment: Are you able to open that file with Excel? What is the value typed in the textbox?

Comment: Yes. The value of textbox is this C:\Users\Boss\Documents\Book123.csv

Comment: Update when the Excel file is opened a different error show. ('dataGridView1_Data$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long). I dont know where dataGridView1_Data$ the name came from and use it

Comment: You are trying to read a Text file, not an Excel one. Different connection string. Look at connectionstrings.com or use a CSV parser library. There are a lots

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I just based the code from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825638/to-insert-csv-file-into-mysql-database-table-using-c-sharp-windows-form. I think i may go different approach of inserting my csv to mysql. thank you for the time.